# Where to place comprobations in Java?

Tags: java

I've come up with this problem over and over again when creating objects that must verify conditions. Should the checks be placed before trying to create the object or in the constructor of the object itself?

To illustrate it better, here's an example: let's say that we have a student manager, a professor, who adds students objects to a list of them. When creating a new student object, we must check that his name is maximum 20 characters long.

```
class Professor{
    LinkedList<Student> studentsList;

    Professor(){
        studentsList = new LinkedList<Student>();
    }

    public Student addStudent(String studentName){
        // Place 1
        if (studentName.length <= 20)
            studentList.add(new Student(studentName));
        else
             // Do another thing
    }
}

class Student {
    String name;

    Student(String studentName){
        // Place 2
        if (studentName.length <= 20)
            name = studentName);
        else
            // Don't create the object and throw exception 
    }
}
```

So basically my question would be, should the checks be done in "Place 1", before trying to create the student, or in "Place 2", in the constructor of students.

Comment: It's up to you. There no right answer.

Comment: Or if there is a convention, which one is mostly used

Comment: I have to disagree with shmosel. If the requirement is to prevent students with names longer than 20 chars, then example one is the _wrong_ answer. It only prevents creating such students in the given example, but not altogether.

Comment: @Tom Example 2 doesn't either, because there might be another constructor without the check. And `name` can be modified after construction. We can only answer in the context of the provided code.

Comment: @shmosel You argue with code style issues of OPs example 2 to defend the conceptual issue of example 1 when it comes to constraint validations?

Comment: @Viktor "comprobations" isn't a word in english but I think you mean "validations."

Comment: @Tom My point is they're both correctly enforcing the constraint *within the provided code*, so it's not accurate to say one of them is wrong. I do understand the point you're making, but it relies on anticipating or inferring additional code, which is ultimately a judgement call.

Comment: @shmosel I wouldn't focus that much about the code OP has posted, but rather the context of each example that OP tried to represent. Thus example one is "outside of the model class; prior creating the object" and example two is "inside the model constructor". A third example could be a factory, but that isn't shown here. Example one relies on the "caller" to check the constraints, but we don't necessarily have control over them, thus we can't enforce such validations or prevent someone else creating a student with a 100 char long name.

Comment: OPs examples may don't show that, but that's what (s)he is asking here about.

Comment: @Tom You seem to be assuming the constraint is on the model rather than the program, but that's not obvious to me from the question. Even if it is, it may be useful to separate the object definition from its validation, as miroxlav discusses.

Comment: @Calicoder Actually, [`comprobations`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comprobation) is indeed a word in English, but is obsolete. Meaning: `(obsolete) joint attestation; proof`, or `(obsolete) approbation` according to Wiktionary.com. Kind of interesting, almost feels like we should resurrect this word for use in a computer science context.

Comment: @BasilBourque I comprobate with you that we should resurrect comprobation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Objects take responsibility for themselves

Generally in [object-oriented programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), we want objects to be responsible for themselves. Business rules regarding the integrity of their internal state should be handled, well, internally (or delegated to a builder -- see below). This idea is part of what is known formally in OOP as [*encapsulation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

So in your example, the `Professor` class should not worrying about the `Student` class’ rules such as length of the student’s name. The `Student` class should be enforcing its own integrity. We want the logic for these integrity rules to be located in one single place, not spread out over your entire app.

Indeed, the **`Professor` class should *not* be instantiating the `Student`** object. Implied in your example is that there must be some other party that is assigning students to a professor. Perhaps a [`Tutorial`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutorial_system) object that is responsible for tracking the assignment and progress of a few students being supervised by a professor. This `Tutorial` should be instantiating the `Student` objects, or passing on the `Student` objects received from some other source such as a database-service object.

By the time the `Student` objects reach the `Professor`, they should be valid. The `Professor` class should not be concerned with what makes a `Student` valid or not. The `Professor` should only be concerned with what makes a `Professor` valid or not.

```
class Professor{
    List< Student > students;
    …
    public void addStudent( Student student ){
        Objects.requireNonNull​( student , "Received NULL rather than a Student object. Message # 68a0ff63-8379-4e4c-850f-e4e06bd8378a." ) ;  // Throw an exception if passed a null object.
        Objects.requireNonNull​( this.students , "Collection of Student objects is NULL. Message # c22d7b22-b450-4122-a4d6-61f92129569a." ) ;  // Throw an exception if the `students` list is not established.
        this.students.add( student ) ;
    }
}
```

Besides the idea of objects being responsible for themselves, another reason for `Professor` to not be instantiating `Student` objects is to facilitate [testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing). If the `Student` objects come from some other source, that source can provide *faux* objects using a `Student` class or interface that is not yet finished, has certain functionality disabled (such as database access), or is substituted with bogus data designed for testing a scenario.

## Builder pattern

If you have multiple properties that need verifying in order to instantiate a new object, you may want to use the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). You define an additional class, such as `StudentBuilder` that has methods for each of the parts needed to make a student.

Often, these methods all return the same `StudentBuilder` object to facilitate [call-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Different folks have different styles for a builder. One way is to provide a validity-checking method, and perhaps a method that provides a list of problems that prevent building the desired object.

Some people use a word like `with` rather than the accessor method `set` to make clear that while we are temporarily setting a property on the builder, the real intention is to be setting a property on an object of another class.

```
StudentBuilder sb = new StudentBuilder().withFirstName( "Alice" ).withLastName( "Coleman" ).withEmail( "x@y.com" );
if( sb.isValid() ) {
    Student s = sb.build() ;
    …
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd never heard of the `java.util.Objects` class until now.  Then again, the last major Java project I worked on was only Java 6...

Answer (score 3):

In simple programs, it does not matter too much. In complex applications there is number of factors which determines this:

- Can objects with invalid values still exist under some conditions? (Do they have their significance even if they contain invalid values?)
- Is validation expensive? (Does it require computing, network connection or database operations?)
- Is validation possible? (Do we already have all the information required for validation?)
- Does the validation have its own phase where this object is validated together with or against others?
- Is there existing convention or requirement?

etc...

So most times, this will become given by architecture or constraints of design or other factors related to larger application. In very small program, you might not find any of those factors determining optimal placement of validations.

In the sample object creation code you show above, you normally won't silently skip values longer than 20 characters but you will typically throw an exception in such a case. If this is data processing and not deliberate *filtering* of records shorter than 20 characters, you don't want to silently omit unsuitable records. (Imagine who will manually check why in set of 1000 records, some 5 records is missing and there was no error message to indicate what has gone wrong. So as maybe you can see, the above approach is not for practical use anyway.)